# How to jQuery select a label inside a div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My dom looks like this:

```
<div class="edit-section slideDown">
  <form>
  <div class="info-header">
    <div class="acct-section-title clearfix">
      <h3 class="acct-section-title-txt pull-left">Meals</h3>
      <button type="button" class="pull-right btn-close icon-close"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="flash-msg"></div>


  <ul class="info-list info-list-form">

    <div class="col-sm-4 info-label"><label for="delivery_name">Name</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 info-value">
      <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <input type="text" name="delivery_name" id="delivery_name" class="form-input">
      </div>
      ...
```

How do I use jQuery to check if the input at the bottom has the dom element:

`<label for="delivery_name">Name</label>`

What's hte best way to check that?

`$('.edit-section')` gets me the outer element but then how do I get the label tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use find for it.

check the following snippet

```js
console.log($(".edit-section").find("label[for =delivery_name]").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit-section slideDown">

  <div class="info-header">
    <div class="acct-section-title clearfix">
      <h3 class="acct-section-title-txt pull-left">Meals</h3>
      <button type="button" class="pull-right btn-close icon-close"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="flash-msg"></div>


  <ul class="info-list info-list-form">

    <div class="col-sm-4 info-label">
      <label for="delivery_name">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 info-value">
      <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <input type="text" name="delivery_name" id="delivery_name" class="form-input">
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Is that the same thing as :`$('.edit-section label[for="delivery_name"]')`

Comment: yes it is the same....find is looking for the children within edit section

Answer (score 4):

> How do I get the label tag?

The most straightforward approach is:

```
$('label[for="delivery_name"]');
```

> How do I use jQuery to check if the input at the bottom has the label?

If `$('label[for="delivery_name"]').length < 1`, then it isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) functions.

Please try this:

```
$('#delivery_name').closest('ul').find('label')
```

Comment: Is `find` the same thing as this but implicit? `$('.edit-section label[for="delivery_name"]')`

Comment: @Jwan622, Yes. `.find()` method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Comment: Also,`closest()` function is very usefull, when you have many `info-list` classes for example.

Answer (score 2):

you can directly target a label `$('.edit-section label[for="delivery_name"]')`

Answer (score 0):

You can access directly to the delivery_name with jQuery.

> $('#delivery_name')

Documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.